# How to count "days with records" in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails adds and populates a `created_at` column for new records.

How can I use the to count the number of days that have records within a specified timeframe? (note: counting days, not counting records).

For example, say I have a Post model, how can I calculate how many days in the last year have a Post?

Comment: do you want to do this with ruby or arel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you asked for the ruby way, here it is:

```
Post.where('created_at >= ?', 1.year.ago).map { |p| p.created_at.beginning_of_day }.uniq.size
```

**Update**

You can put the following in your Post model

```
def self.number_of_days
  where('created_at >= ?', 1.year.ago).map { |p| p.created_at.beginning_of_day }.uniq.size
end
```

Then in your controller you can do stuff like

```
@user.posts.number_of_days
```

Here's a more efficient way that delegates most of the work to the database (MySQL, not sure if it'll work on others):

```
Post.where('created_at >= ?', 1.year.ago).group('DATE(created_at)').length
```

Comment: thanks xnm. I want to use this in a view, for example `@user.number_of_post_days`. How would you implement your solution? Define your query in the controller with an instance variable and then call it in the view? Or is there a mor efficient approach given my use case?

Comment: You can just assign it to any instance variable in the controller and it will be available to the view. `@number_of_post_days` would be fine.

Comment: thanks xnm. I was think more along the lines of efficiency. For example, in a users index view, this may result in a lot of database calls. I may have to think about cache this number in a column. Anyway, I'd welcome your suggestions, but this is beyond my original question. Thanks for your answer!!

Comment: Well I gave you the more inefficient (ruby) way, since that's what you asked for. I've added a bit more efficient method as well.